# Compiler and linker library paths when building Boost

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, path, include

I'm building Boost for a project I'm doing (I'm using visual studio 2015 and windows 10, in case the OS is relevant).

It builds fine (using the command prompt), but gives me the following "warning", and I'm not sure if I should ignore it or not:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
C:\Local\boost_1_61_0
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
C:\Local\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib
```

How should I proceed with this? What am I supposed to do with these paths?

Comment: What is exactly not clear with this message? You do know what your compiler, include paths, linker and library paths are for, right?

Comment: You should do what it says for whatever project you need boost (otherwise your compiler will not be able to find / use boost). For your projects that don't need boost you don't have to modify your compiler / linker settings.

Comment: Reworded to be clearer, fixed typo in title, improved message formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to use the boost library in your own project, you will need to set the include search path and library search path to include those noted above so that the compiler can successfully find the include and library files.

Comment: Everyone keeps talking about include paths and linker paths, but I have no idea what those are and where shall I search for them. How can I even get the knowledge, when it is always "you know right?" answer?

Comment: The question was based on here are my paths what should I do with them - not how do I find my paths. Also is compiler dependant, IDE dependant ...